# cocoa objective-c for os x : get volume mount point from path

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I would like to find the mount point of a volume for a given NSString path.

Though I'm a beginner in Cocoa and objective-C, I'm trying to do this "elegantly", ie. using one of the provided class, rather than making an external shell call or listing mounted filesystems and finding which one the path belongs to.

I did find NSWorkspace and getFileSystemInfoForPath, but it does not mention the mount point.

Can anybody help ?

thanks

Comment: Path to what? A file on the volume, the device backing the volume, or something else?

Comment: a path to a file on the Volume

Comment: I don't think there's a Cocoa method for that. For what purpose do you need the mount point? The solution would depend on that. For example, the mount point would change if the volume name is changed from the Finder; do you want the volume name, or something unique to the device, independent of the volume name a user assigns to it?

Answer (score 4):

This should go something along those lines:

```
+ (NSString*)volumeNameForPath:(NSString *)inPath
{
    HFSUniStr255 volumeName;
    FSRef volumeFSRef;
    unsigned int volumeIndex = 1;

    while (FSGetVolumeInfo(kFSInvalidVolumeRefNum, volumeIndex++, NULL, kFSVolInfoNone, NULL, &volumeName, &volumeFSRef) == noErr) {
        NSURL *url = [(NSURL *)CFURLCreateFromFSRef(NULL, &volumeFSRef) autorelease];
        NSString *path = [url path];

        if ([inPath hasPrefix:path]) {
            return [NSString stringWithCharacters:volumeName.unicode length:volumeName.length]
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Failure case: Two volumes exist, “Volume with a long name” and “Volume”. The input path is “/Volumes/Volume with a long name/Some file”, and the loop gets to “/Volumes/Volume” first. Your method returns “/Volumes/Volume”, which is the wrong one.

Comment: thanks for the proposal. But I also discovered a problem with it.
If I use the path 
/Volumes/NO NAME/some/dir/in/bootcamp
the returned volume is the name of the os x partition.
I was hoping there was some class/method way of finding this information, rather than resorting to string manipulation to guess the volume.

Comment: This is untested code which I did not even try to compile. Errors and edge cases are to be expected. It derives from code I wrote for the Aperture parser in the iMedia browser. There I have the volume name stored by Aperture and need to find the full path.

I guess the failure case could be resolved by making sure the path string ends with a /.

Comment: This is also quite inefficient, scanning all mounted volumes just to test them against a single file.

Answer (score 1):

I've run by this a month after it has been asked, but anyway: in Python standard library there's [`os.path.ismount()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.ismount) function, which detects if a path is a mount point. From its description it does it so:

> The function checks whether `path`‘s parent, `path/..`, is on a different device than `path`, or whether `path/..` and `path` point to the same i-node on the same device — this should detect mount points for all Unix and POSIX variants.